# How to fix "signal SIGABRT" when using self.UISegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex

Tags: objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol, sigabrt

each time I using `"self.SegControl.selectedSegmentIndex"`, I would get `SIGABRT` signal in the following `code` :

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,     NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));// signal SIGABRT
    }
}
```

I tried to find the value of `self.SegControl.selectedSegmentIndex` :

```
long a=self.SegControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
```

However, I find out I even cannot use `self.SegControl.selectedSegmentIndex`.

```
...
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *SegControl;
...
- (IBAction)Button:(id)sender {
NSMutableString *str=[NSMutableString new];
if(self.SegControl.selectedSegmentIndex==0){
    [str appendString:@"unit 2"];
}
else if(self.SegControl.selectedSegmentIndex==1){
    [str appendString:@"unit 3"];
}
else if(self.SegControl.selectedSegmentIndex==2){
    [str appendString:@"unit 4"];
}
self.Output.text=str;
}
...
```

I wanna get the output of self.SegControl.selectedSegmentIndex. I wanna let my program know which segment is chosen.
Please help me out!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is any index selected at the moment of the if statement?

In your storyboard, do you have any selected index as default value? There is a check box where you can set the behavior of the default selected index. Or you should do it programmatically before the if statements.

[image]